# Pandoc Error producing PDF with markdown body text and YAML metadata file

Tags: latex, yaml, pandoc

I'm running the following Pandoc 2.0.3 command on the Mac Terminal command line:

```
pandoc one.md "metadata.yaml" -o two.pdf
```

This should take the markdown file `one.md` and output `two.pdf` using the yaml file `metadata.yaml`, a minimal version of which is:

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
...
```

This Pandoc run produces a PDF as expected for the following version of `one.md`:

```
# Report
```

**However, it fails** to produce a PDF for the following version of `one.md`, which contains body text:

```
# Report

Lorem.
```

The resulting error message is:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.65 header-includes: - \usepackage
```

I don't understand why including that one word creates a failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `one.md` likely doesn't end with a newline.  Pandoc concatenates all input files, adding a *single* newline between files. So the resulting input will be:

```
# Report

Lorem.
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
...
```

As a result, the opening dashes of the YAML block are interpreted as underlines for `Lorem.`, which is then read as a second-level header.  This doesn't happen if the line above the `---` dashes is an ATX-style header.

Just add a newline to the end of `one.md` and everything should work the way you expected.

Comment: This answer solved the problem. A new line is required.